# Left join filtering null values with custom function in where

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, left-join

I have a table referencing city table with a key called `cityId`.
I fetch data from it using this query:

```
SELECT t.ID, city.areaId FROM transp t
LEFT JOIN city ON city.ID = t.cityId;
```

Like this, it returns the table as is, with NULL for `city.areaId` If the `cityId` was null.

But when I add function to the where clause that is using `city.areaId`, even function that is always true, the query does not show rows in which the `cityId` is null. for example:

```
SELECT t.ID, city.areaId FROM transp t
LEFT JOIN city ON city.ID = t.cityId
WHERE always_true(city.areaId);
```

Will not show any rows with null `cityId`. I don't understand why this happens, because I am using an `left join` and if I put the function in the SELECT, I can see that it indeed is always true.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9b12c5/3)

Comment: Looks like a MySQL bug.  It behaves correctly with an expression in the `where` such as `1=1`.

Comment: Can you send a link to the correct behavior using 1=1 in sqlfiddle? I couldn't repeat that

Comment: Yep, this behaviour is very strange. I would expect both records to show up. It is worth to raise it as a MySQL bug and see what MySQL devs come up with as an answer.

Comment: If you move `always_true(city.areaId)` to the having clause, then it works. But this is not the point.

Answer (score 4):

Well, though looks like MySQL does some internal optimization that I would say is buggy (converting left join to inner in that case is incorrect) there is a workaround

```
SELECT t.ID, city.areaId
FROM transp t
LEFT JOIN city ON city.ID = t.cityId
WHERE always_true(coalesce(city.areaId, null));
```

Comment: Thank you! This *does* work, but I'm not sure if to mark that as accepted answer, as this is not a real fix.

Comment: You know, if I were you I would report this bug to  MySQL bugtracker as the _real_ fix should be in C code

Comment: What's more interesting that MySQL treats a built-in function (coalesce()) differently from an UDF (always_true())